# The meaning of 'hx,xedge = np.histogram(x,xgrid)'

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

Below is a program about binomially distributed random. In this code, I don't understand the sentence `hx,xedge = np.histogram(x,xgrid)`.

What does it do? Is histogram used to draw a bar graph?

I make the line chart with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=12)
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=12)
#generate random number from binomial density
# with test number of 10 and probability of event of 0.4
x = np.random.binomial(10,0.4,size=1000)
print(x)
#analyze the random samples with a histogram
xgrid = np.arange(0.5,20.5,1)
xcenter = (xgrid[1:]+xgrid[0:len(xgrid)-1])/2.
hx,xedge = np.histogram(x,xgrid)
#draw the histogram
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,5])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(xcenter,hx,'ko-')
fig.savefig('binomrand_hist.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [documentation for `numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram)?

This function takes some data (here `x`), and a sequence of bins (here `xgrid`), and return the number of observations in each bins, as well as the values of the edges of each bin as a tuple `(hx,xedge)`.

Later, the script plots the number of observations (`hx`) vs the center position of each bins (calculated as `xcenter`), using the line:

```
ax.plot(xcenter,hx,'ko-')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i know the documentation. but your answer make me more clear.